# How can I eliminate Greek Characters on my app?

Tags: java, javascript, html, jsp, struts-1

I'm developing an app on Struts 1.x. My problem is that my main menu is showed not in Spanish (which is my language) but in Greek!, at first I thought it was a problem with the encoding I was using so I changed it to ISO-8859-1 but this didn't work either.

I am currently deploying my app on a remote server and its there where I get this error. The other thing is this error only appears on every browser used in Windows except for Mozilla Firefox, my app looks fine on every browser in Linux.

[This is how my menu looks like from Google Chrome on Windows 7](https://i.stack.imgur.com/5hrCY.png)

Any ideas of how can I fix this?

Thanks in advance!

Comment: Why would you want to change it? Greek is awesome!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It looks like your app is being shown with the Symbol font, where latin letters are replaced by Greek equivalents. If you know are familiar with the alphabet you can read the text in the image and see that it actually says "Inicio" and "Ayuda" for example.

Edit the CSS to change the font from Symbol to Arial for example.